# Error uploading zip with curl on Catalina OSX 10.15.1

Tags: mac-osx, curl

Using curl command tool pre-installled in OSx.

Command like:

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization:Bearer xxx' -H 'Accept:application/json' -F 'funzione=uploadPacket' -F 'folder_id=159' -F 'userfile=@//Users/mediabook/Desktop/forCatalina.zip' https://mysite/api/extGetNote
```

In previous systems it worked properly.
Now with Catalina ( OSX 10.15.0 and 10.15.1) reports this error:

```
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

Verbose:

```
*   Trying 95.141.37.143...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mysite (95.141.37.143) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
 CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN= mysite
*  start date: Oct 22 08:06:23 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 20 08:06:23 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "mysite" matched cert's "mysite"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fb230008c00)
POST /api/extGetNote HTTP/2
Host: mysite
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Authorization:Bearer xxx
Accept:application/json
Content-Length: 160026
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------6cec1f7bf39b0dbf

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* stopped the pause stream!
* Connection #0 to host mysite left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* Closing connection 0
```

Same command with jpeg attachment works!
Error only with zip file.
The file is 160 Kb….

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using HTTP/2. Add the option `--http1.1` to your `curl` command.